# Mesh information (vertices, links, triangles) from model in Rviz

Tags: rviz, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How could I obtain the mesh information rendered from a model from URDF/XACRO file after being rendered in Rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256102/mesh-information-(vertices,-links,-triangles)-from-model-in-rviz/) by [Huskinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28894/huskinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't. That is not supported in RViz.

I'd use a tool like Blender or Meshlab.

---

Edit: if with "links" you mean nr of links in the model / scene, then counting the nr of TF frames in your scene could give you that information, albeit a bit indirectly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0